# Read from serial port with timeout between bytes in .NET

Tags: c#, serial-port

I would like to read some data from a serial port. However, the packets of data are not well defined - there is no fixed length or end character. What I do to solve this is I wait until the serial port stops sending data for a short time, say 50ms, and then I say one transmission is complete. In Python, I can use the `inter_byte_timeout` feature of pyserial for this. I am confident the device will send all bytes in one go, so this works.

How do I do it in C#? I have been using `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`, but I am open to other solutions.

What doesn't work is the normal `ReadTimeout` property. That only waits until the first byte. Read will then return an arbitrary amount of data. I also can't use `ReceivedBytesThreshold`, since I don't know how many bytes it will be in total.

Comment: Then you cannot process the data.  Only applications like a chat program where application is not parsing data can work using timeouts  In c# I would not use timeouts but instead use Asynchronous method.

Comment: What kind of data is it? Without defining packets, what is the usage of *some bytes* you receive? If packet is defined (e.g. it has header, to know the size in advance), then you can continuously read the data, concatenating all recieved bytes together and processing them as they come. Btw, serial port will do concatenation anyway inside its buffer, you may not be able to take one packet before second is started. Afair with timeouts you can only discard data.

Comment: Why not try using the Win32API directly in P/Invoke or C++/CLI instead of the .NET SerialPort class? For example, you can set the timeout in detail with this API. [SetCommTimeouts function (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommtimeouts), [COMMTIMEOUTS structure (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-commtimeouts) However, you will need to use everything directly, including CreateFile/CloseHandle/ReadFile/WriteFile, not just some settings.